# Are these the same color: Yarok vs. Karti?

Tags: color

What is the difference between Yarok and Karti?  Aren't they both green?  And if so, then why are two separate words necessary?

Comment: Are Hebrew-language questions off-topic?  These words appears in the Mishnayot and I want to understand their meanings.

Comment: Re scope, see the answer http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/164 and its comments.

Comment: @msh210 I assume you remember this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15347/759

Comment: I vote to reopen only to reclose it as a duplicate of ^^^^