# PTIJ: Why do Ipods come in only 3 colors?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Shemot 28:6 says:

ועשו את האפוד זהב תכלת וארגמן

You shall make the Ipod gold, blue and scarlet

Why does the Torah limit making the Ipod only in these 3 colors? What's so special about these 3 specifc colors for Ipods?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: What happened to תולעת שני and שש משזר? Did they discontinue those models?

Comment: Also, what kind of an iPod are we talking about here? Is it an iPod Touch, an iPod Nano, or an iPod Shuffle?

Comment: @DonielF 1st comment - those are not colors. 2nd comment - come up with a clever answer, my friend. I've always been an Android owner, so I don't much about all these models to answer your question.

Comment: תולעת is a color. Sefaria translates ארגמן as purple and תולעת שני as scarlet thread. But they also translate אפוד as, er, an ephod.

Comment: @DonielF Learned something. What color is תולעת? I can always update the question.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure anymore. Is תולעת scarlet and שני thread, or is it the other way around?

Comment: @doniel תולעת is worm and שני is scarlet. It's a scarlet color that derives from a worm.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks for the explanation. It seems that I have mistranslated the word ארגמן, too. IY"H, I'll edit the question later.

Comment: @DonielF I think it's all three - the iPod Touch comes in gold, the iPod Nano comes in blue, and the iPod Shuffle comes in scarlet.

Comment: @DonialF Vayikra 13:20: וְרָאָה הַכֹּהֵן וְהִנֵּה מַרְאֶהָ שָׁפָל -- The kohen will look and behold -- it's appearance of shuffle

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Talmud (Sotah 17a) comments:

> ר"מ אומר מה נשתנה תכלת מכל מיני צבעונין מפני שהתכלת דומה לים וים דומה לרקיע...‏
>   Rabbi Meir said: How is blue different from all other colors? Because blue reminds one of the sea, and the sea reminds one of the skies, and the sky reminds us of the Cloud...

The iPod comes in blue so you never forget where your songs are stored.

Incidentally, your translation of ארגמן and זהב as "scarlet" and "gold" separately is mistaken. It just refers to one color: "rose gold".

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35123/9682

Answer (score 5):

One answer is that that was only the first generation of Ipods.  In the second generation there were more colors, as is said (Shemos 25:7):

> מִלֻּאִים לָאֵפֹד

Another possibility is that  the other colors of Ipod found in the world are counterfeit and came from Micha, as it says:

> וְהָאִ֣ישׁ מִיכָ֔ה ל֖וֹ בֵּ֣ית אֱלֹהִ֑ים וַיַּ֤עַשׂ אֵפוֹד֙

Answer (score 4):

You have to make the Ipod in ארגמן so that when you do tshuva, it will turn white... this is the mekor for having visible hechsharim on smartphones 'וכו.

Why it should be זהב is still a problem though, as ...אלוקי זהב לא תעשה לך