# "Tekhelet=Turquoise Wool"?

Tags: translation

In the Artscroll Chumash Bamidbar 15:38, Tekhelet is translated as "turquoise wool". Does anyone have information on how 'wool' is derived from the word 'Tekhelet' or from the verse in which it is found?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm more curious where they get turquoise from when Rashi very clearly translates it as green.

Comment: @DonielF not necessarily green https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15347/759

Comment: @DonielF - It is common in Mishnaic and Medieval Hebrew to use the word _yarok_ to talk about blue and green, similar to the way that the Japanese word for green (_ao_) can also mean blue. Maybe you'd be interested in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue%E2%80%93green_distinction_in_language) which discusses blue-green distinction in languages. (Keep in mind that the Hebrew they reference is Modern Israeli Hebrew.)

Comment: Why would a word that also means vegetation (i.e. greenery - ירק) mean any color but green? @DoubleAA

Comment: @ezra ^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @doniel oh ירק does mean green. It also means yellow. And chartreuse.

Comment: @DoubleAA What vegetable is blue, or even turquoise?

Comment: @doniel you clearly need to listen to more Bill Monroe :) but I don't know why I have to find a plant with a certain hue in order for it to be included in the color called ירוק.

Comment: @DoubleAA Who? [char]

Comment: @DonielF http://lmgtfy.com/?q=bill%20monroe

Comment: @DoubleAA Bill Monroe, the father of bluegrass music? I heard him live many years ago on his farm in Brown County, Indiana. But what does that have to do with tekhelet?

Comment: @yaaco he asked me to identify a blue plant... That must have been a cool experience!

Comment: @DoubleAA It was an incredible performance. I was thinking you were making a sideways reference to Muleskinner Blues or Blue Yodel. ;-)

Comment: @Doniel - Easy. Blue is a shade of green (or vice versa). In those days, perhaps that's the way they saw blue. It's hard for us to imagine, because we've been brought up from an early age knowing that blue is blue and green is green, but who knows?

Comment: @DonielF see also comments on [the question DoubleAA linked to above](/q/15347)

Answer (score 4):

*Tekhelet* refers to a specific dyed textile prized in the ancient world. Traditionally and according to contemporary archeological understanding, the textile comprised wool dyed a blueish color with a specific sea creature, possibly identified with the [hexaplex trunculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexaplex_trunculus) (or a subspecies thereof).  (While very specific, that is the accepted meaning of the word, just as *zahav* refers to a specific metal - gold.)

Comment: Maybe include the gemara in yebamot 4b in your answer. It clearly identifies  Tekhlet with wool!

Comment: Well, wool is what Menachot says, although I wouldn't say turquoise

Answer (score 4):

[**Yevamot 4b**](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=4b&format=pdf)

> ותנא דבי רבי ישמעאל כל בגדים צמר ופשתים הם ואמר רחמנא עביד ליה תכלת ותכלת עמרא הוא וממאי דתכלת עמרא הוא מדשש כיתנא תכלת עמרא הוא
>
> a Tanna of the School of R. Ishmael [taught]: Wherever ‘garment’ [is written] such as is made of wool or flax [is meant], and yet the All Merciful said that in them ‘purple’ shall be inserted, and purple, surely, is wool. And whence is it deduced that purple is wool? Since linen<sup>34</sup> is flax, purple must be wool.<sup>35</sup>
>
> ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/yebamoth/yebamoth_4.html))

As the footnotes explain (essentially Rashi’s explanation):

> **(34)** In the description of the materials of the High Priests’ garments (Ex. XXXIX, 1ff).
>
> **(35)** As the garments were either of wool or flax, and linen (flax) was specified in the case of one, all the others must have been wool.

Answer (score 2):

In actuality, the term (in this pasuk) refers to any thread which is to be dyed. However, the normal usage of the term (without the kind of fabric being dyed) means wool as in the construction of the mishkan and the priestly clothing.

Rav Hirsch explains on [Beha'aloscha 15:38](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9943#v=38&showrashi=true)

> דַּבֵּר אֶל בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל וְאָמַרְתָּ אֲלֵהֶם וְעָשׂוּ לָהֶם
>   צִיצִת עַל כַּנְפֵי בִגְדֵיהֶם לְדֹרֹתָם וְנָתְנוּ עַל צִיצִת הַכָּנָף
>   פְּתִיל תְּכֵלֶת:

Note that `פְּתִיל תְּכֵלֶת` means a thread that is dyed with the color techeiles.

Rav Hirsch explains that the basic beged referenced in the Torah is wool or linen. However, the usage of the terms in [Tetzaveh 28:5](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9889#v=5&showrashi=true)

> וְהֵם יִקְחוּ אֶת הַזָּהָב וְאֶת הַתְּכֵלֶת וְאֶת הָאַרְגָּמָן וְאֶת
>   תּוֹלַעַת הַשָּׁנִי וְאֶת הַשֵּׁשׁ
>
> They shall take the gold, the blue, purple, and crimson wool, and the
>   linen,

Shows that when the name of the dye alone is used, then it refers to the dyed wool, as opposed to the linen which is referred to separately.

We therefore, refer to the term *techeiles* as **normally** wool dyed with techeiles

> **בגדיהם** We have repeatedly had occasion to remark -- at the בגדי כהונה
>   -- that in the Torah wool and linen are taken as the real materials used
>   for clothes, and hence by בגדים סתם as a rule only woolen or
>   linen garments are to be understood.

Rav Hirsch also points out that the connection of [Ki Teitzei 11-12](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9986#v=11&showrashi=true) leads to the statement that tzitis made out of wool or linen are valid for garments made out of any material, but if made out of other materials are only valid for garments made out of the same material (see רשבא on Sab. 27b).

Comment: תְּכֵלֶת is also mentioned at the beginning of Esther regarding the way the palace was decorated. It is used again regarding the royal clothes that Mordechai wore to celebrate the decree that the Jews could defend themselves. What are these 2 items? Up to you if you want to include these refs in your answer.

Comment: @DanF I would rather not because it is better to connect a pasuk to a Torah reference. The reference in Esther would refer to the pasuk to explain what is meant there rather than the other way around.

Comment: I'm not clear on where there is any indication in the verses you cited that the term ever means anything other than the wool dyed with the specific dye extracted from the chilazon?

Comment: @Loewian That is the point that I was making. The connection to the bigdei kehuna shows that.