# What do colors represent in Chassidus and Kabbalah

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, color, emes-truth-honesty

BH

Is there a more deeper explanation to colors in Chassidus and Kabbalah?

Like hidden meanings of different colors or more higher explanation of them in Seder hishtalshelut or in the spiritual levels?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15346/31534

Answer (score 0):

In the Hakdama of דעת ותבונה (R Yosef Hayyim of Baghdad) it is said that there are colours in the השתלשלות however the colours are not literal but rather serve as a symbol of divine reality.