# Is there any halachic or recommended consistency needed for charoset?

Tags: food, passover, passover-seder-hagada

I've seen charoset made in various consistencies. Some are chunky with loose pieces of apples and nuts in a bit of wine or grape juice - the wine is not incorporated into the mix, so the pieces are just marinating in the wine.

Others make more of a loose mix. It looks much like applesauce with a few apple chunks and crunchy nut pieces. It has a loose consistency.

Others make it very thick, probably by adding a lot of ground nuts. If you put the charoset on a spoon and hold the spoon upside down, the charoset sticks to the spoon for a while.

Is there any halachic requirement or minhagim for the thickness / consistency of charoset?

Comment: maybe it has to do with whether you think it is a reminder of the apples or of the mortar. The gemara in Pesachim 116a says it has to have apples and be thick. Your mortar may vary.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6848

Answer (score 1):

Chabad specifically makes it chunky and dry in order not to cause problems with gebrokts